# How to map xml fields without parent tag to java list?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have following xml response from web service which need to map to java class.

```
<api1Response>
   <timeStamp>06/24/2016 07:45:10</timeStamp>
   <ippProjectName>xyz</ippProjectName>
   <project>
      <projectId>1</projectId>
      <projectName>ABC</projectName>
      <dataDate>06/06/2016</dataDate>
   </project>
   <project>
      <projectId>2</projectId>
      <projectName>PQR</projectName>
      <dataDate>06/06/2016</dataDate>
   </project>
</api1Response>
```

I have mapping class like

```
class api1Response{
    String timeStamp;
    String ippProjectName;
    //how to map project
}
```

As project tags not having any parent element how i can map it to List using jaxb.
I know it will be easy if "project" tags having parent elements like "projects" but response is not in my control and i still need to parse it with jaxb.

Comment: If you map it to java list, shouldn't it be called "projects"? But what if there's also a tag call "projects"? I don't think it's possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just using XmlElement over a list of projects shoud do the trick :

```
class api1Response{
    String timeStamp;
    String ippProjectName;
    @XmlElement(name="project")
    List<Project> projects;
}
```